# How to exit out of window in pygame 64 bit?

Tags: python, error-handling, crash, pygame

I have created a window in pygame, the only problem is that I can't exit the window without it crashing. Is there a problem with my code that causes this?

```
import pygame        
pygame.init()    
gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode ((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption ('snake')

pygame.display.update()
while True:
    pass

gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: the `while True: pass` loop takes a while until you get to the `gameExit` loop... :)

Comment: Do you know any way this could be written better?

Comment: find some tutorial - for example http://programarcadegames.com/

Comment: the `while True: pass` loop isn't actually doing anything, so you could remove it

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of this:

```
while True:
    pass
```